I can't able to use live server in vscode
while clicking the go live in live server option this message popping out Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, stat 'd:\System Volume Information' And I cant able to use it what I have to do please response me
Thank you sir/mam
I just reinstall but it not working

Normally, Windows doesn't allow you to access a drive's "System Volume Information" directory. Is Django trying to access this directory? Do you know why?
